# Why I can't use parent's function in parent's class when using override in child's class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func_1(self,a,b):
        #do some stuff
    
    def other_func(self,a,b):
        if b:
            self.func_1(a,b)
        else:
            #do other stuff



class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
    
    def func_1(self):
        for i in range(10):
            super().func_1(i,i+1)
```

When I do this:

```
b = B()
b.other_func(5,5)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: func_1() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Why is this and how should this be done? I thought that when calling `other_func` I would be using `func_1` from `A` and not the override one from `B`

Comment: Beside the point, but both those `__init__` methods are pointless. `A` will automatically inherit from `object`, so you don't need to specify it, and `B` will automatically inherit from `A`. For the sake of example, please remove them. For reference, see [mre].

Comment: Because in `b.other_func` calls `self.func_1(a,b)` which is `B.func_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `self` is an instance of `B`, so `self.func_1(...)` is equivalent to `B.func_1(self, ...)`.

As for how to fix it, it depends on what `func_1` actually does, and what its actual name is for that matter. You could possibly:

1. Rename one of them
2. [Make a private or class-private copy](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) of `A.func_1`

   1. Or, if it's not actually used publicly, rename it so that it's private or class-private itself
3. Use `A.func_1(self, a, b)` in `A.other_func`, **but** that'd prevent other child classes from *properly* overriding `func_1`, so I don't recommend it. I don't think it has any advantages over using a class-private copy.

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea !... using your second suggestion actually worked. I also tried to do `__func_1 = func_1` right after the definition of the class, but it didn't worked. Why is that? (It worked by doing it at the end of the class)

Comment: @xerac That's explained in the link: *"This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, **as long as it occurs within the definition of a class**."*

Comment: @xerac Oh, actually, mainly it didn't work because those names aren't defined outside of the class scope. You'd have to specify the class name *plus* the mangling: `A._A__func_1 = A.func_1`